# Apply UTF8 encoding when writing Scala Dataframe into CSV file

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, utf-8

How can I apply UTF8 encoding properly when writing a dataframe into a CSV file in Spark2-Scala? I am using this:

```
df.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|")
.save(Path)
```

And it is not working: example: replacing é to weird strings.

Thank you.

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding used by Spark.

Comment: @Shaido Why am I having weird characters in output then? I checked my DF in Spark-Shell and it is good

Comment: can you post the images of your shell & other for better understanding.

Comment: Try setting the `encoding` option explicitly to `UTF-8`, though that's the default encoding if the option is unset. Perhaps Spark is running with a different locale.

Comment: @SarathChandraVema It is simple. When I do df.show in spark-Shell I can see the real desired strings like: monté or frère. But when I go look into the CSV file I get things like mont@A and weird chars.

Comment: @HristoIliev do you mean something like .option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1") ?

Comment: I mean `.option("encoding", "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as @Hristo Iliev suggested I needed to force UTF encoding using:

```
df.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format("csv").option("header", true).option("encoding", "UTF-8").option("delimiter", "|")
.save(Path)
```