# Special characters not encoded properly when creating Spark dataframe from parquet

Tags: apache-spark, utf-8, apache-spark-sql, character-encoding, parquet

My input parquet file has a column defined as `optional binary title (UTF8);`, which may include special characters such as the German umlat (i.e. Schrödinger).

When using Spark to load the contents of the parquet to a DataFrame, the contents of the row are loading the value **Schrödinger** as **SchrÃ¶dinger**. I believe the best explanation of why this could be happening is answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360502/how-to-handle-german-umlauts-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-%C3%BC), though I was under the impression that Spark will read the parquet file as UTF-8 by default anyway.

I have attempted to force UTF-8 encoding by using the option argument as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482570/apply-utf8-encoding-when-writing-scala-dataframe-into-csv-file), but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with encoding CP1252. It worked for us for most of the special characters which are not supported in UTF8.